# Ipad screen blinking/flickering randomly while running my application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-management, ios6

[image: In the image attached, the area is marked with Red borders which start blinking]
Most of the times when I run my application , the marked area starts blinking continuously. Sometime , the left and right margin of the iPad also starts blinking. It happens randomly.
I would like to know whether **its a hardware issue** , which is happening on my iPad only(iPad 3)
or it has something to do with my **application memory allocation** .

I have done quite a search on the web regarding this but cant find anything.

About my application :
It captures data from the user on the table form , then we capture some images using av foundation and upload the data and images on the server . The uploading is done asynchronously .I also perform some image operations on the images captured.

Note- This blinking/Flickering only happens when I run my application and that too randomly. iOS version is 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with one of my application ,in which I was using the high defination images . If you are running your app on to non-retina device , the images getting consumed at that time should be low resolution ,i.e. Suppose you are setting a background image for any view then you must be having you must be having to images for background . let one be having resolution (320*480) for non-retina , and another (640*960) for retina . also you must follow the naming convention so that the device automatically the right image according to the device's resolution .

```
backgroundImage~iphone.png     (for non-retina iphone)
backgroundImage~iphone@2x.png  (for retina iphone)
backgroundImage.png            (for non-retina ipad)
backgroundImage@2x.png         (for retina ipad)
```

Also check the memory allocation using the Instrument in XCode and release the un-necessary wherever possible

Hope it will help you !

Comment: @gourav Thanks for the quick reply , I am using iPad 3 which supports retina display. So high-defination images wont be a problem.Also I am not using any high-def images.